# ROS Answers SE migration: publish a char

Tags: arduino, rosserial, rostopic

[image: Rosanswers logo]

hey community,
im a ROS beginner, and my question is
how can i publish a char manualy in a rostopic?
i have published a string with

rostopic pub -1 my_topic std_msgs/String x

but the comand

rostopic pub -1 my_topic std_msgs/Char x

fails

edit:

when i try:

fhduser@fhduser:~/catkin_ws/src/sekuria$ rostopic pub -1 my_topic std_msgs/Char a

i get: [WARN] [WallTime: 1391591690.683859] Inbound TCP/IP connection failed: global name '_x' is not defined

when i try:

fhduser@fhduser:~/catkin_ws/src/sekuria$ rostopic pub -1 my_topic std_msgs/Char data: a

i get:

ERROR: Too many arguments:

- Given: [{'data': None}, 'a']
- Expected: ['data']

Args are: [data]

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/126336/publish-a-char/) by [sonyfuchs](https://answers.ros.org/users/11651/sonyfuchs/) on ROS Answers with karma: 5 on 2014-02-04

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

This looks like a bug with how `std_msgs/msg/_Char.py` is generated. Indeed, _x is never defined, whereas in `std_msgs/msg/_String.py`, it is defined in the serialize function. I would suggest submitting a bug report against [ros_comm](https://github.com/ros/ros_comm/issues/new).

---

Originally posted by [Dan Lazewatsky](https://answers.ros.org/users/173/dan-lazewatsky/) with karma: 9115 on 2014-02-05

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0